# numpy: efficient sum of kronecker products

Tags: numpy, vectorization, kronecker-product

- I have three sets of matrices {A_i}, {B_i}, and {C_i} with n matrices in each set
- The A_i are of dimension l x m, the B_i are of dimension m x o and the C_i are of dimension p x q
- I would like to compute the following: [image]

Here is a concrete example for what I am after

```
A = np.arange(12).reshape(2,3,2)
B = np.arange(12,24).reshape(2,2,3)
C = np.arange(32).reshape(2,4,4)

result = np.zeros((12,12))
for i in range(2):
    result += np.kron(A[i,:,:] @ B[i,:,:], C[i,:,:])
```

How can I implement this more efficiently?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked into [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I had a look and came up with something (see below). Can we make it more efficient?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, I had a look into [numpy.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). This turned out to be quite nice. A solution is:

```
np.einsum('ijk,imn->jmkn', np.einsum('ijk,ikm->ijm', A, B), C).reshape(A.shape[1] * C.shape[1], B.shape[2] * C.shape[2])
```

- The inner `np.einsum()` produces a 3d array of the products of the 2d "slices" of `A` and `B`
- The outer `np.einsum()` mimics (after appropriate reshaping) the kronecker product of this 3d matrix and `C` and summation.

I found the following two posts very helpful:

- [Understanding NumPy's einsum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089893/understanding-numpys-einsum)
- [Speeding Up Kronecker Products Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067643/speeding-up-kronecker-products-numpy)

Comment: For larger arrays it's faster to combine both `einsum` calls and `optimize` the contraction with `np.einsum('ijk,ikm,ino->jnmo', A, B, C, optimize='optimal').reshape(A.shape[1] * C.shape[1], -1)`. Using `float64` arrays speeds up by ~5x, `float32` by ~10x because `int` arrays aren't using parallel BLAS calls with `numpy`. Might be worth converting to `float`.

Comment: Thanks. The speedup from this - for larger arrays - is incredible!